# Running code in a PHP once

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a class in PHP that acts as a wrapper for a collection of command line tools to make them easier to use from PHP.

I have a single class (`MyClass`) in a file `myclass.php`.

I have code that checks to see if the required tools are installed and then sets a constant (`TOOLS_AVAILABLE`) to either `true` or `false`. Although it's not a lot of code, I only want it to run the first time somebody tries to instantiate my class **or** use any of its static functions. What's the best practice for handling this?

Comment: You could keep track of the tools available in a database or file somewhere and refer to that instead, only running your script every now and then to update what tools it knows about.

Comment: Once per user? Or installation?  Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only want it to run the first time somebody tries to instantiate my class or use any of its static functions.

Well, the best answer is not to have any static methods. Then you can stick the code in a constructor method as per the answer by @treegarden.

If you *must* have static methods, then you'll need a static flag within the class to indicate when you've called the 'run once' code, so you can avoid running it again. And then call it explicitly from each of your static methods and the constructor. Something like this:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    private static $hasRunOnce = false;

    private static runMeOnce()
    {
        if (!self::$hasRunOnce) {
            self::$hasRunOnce = true;
            //put your 'run once' code here...
        }
    }

    public static oneOfYourStaticMethods()
    {
        self::runMeOnce();
        //put your static method code here...
        //this would be the same for each of your static methods and your constructor.
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. Can I ask why static methods are a (design-wise) no go??

Comment: @Garry -- your situation is a good example of one reason why static methods are bad. What you're trying to do is the kind of thing that constructors were invented for; using static means you have to revert to work-arounds like this. Static methods can also be very difficult to work with when writing unit tests -- [see here](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html) for a discussion on that. On the flip-side, the one area where static methods are considered good practice is when used as a "factory method"; ie a method that is called to create an obect in place of `new`.

Comment: Essentially my static methods are factory methods. Before I can return new instances of the class I need to check that certain tools are installed (otherwise the code will fail).

Comment: Another option would be to move those checks and related code out into their own class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `__construct` function in your class and put whatever code you want to execute on instantiation in there:

```
class MyClass {
    function __construct(/* arguments */) {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```

The code will get executed only once when someone instantiates the class.

Comment: I updated my question. There are several public static methods provided by the class too and I would have to have the tool-checking code execute before they run too

Comment: then create a private function called for example `onStaticExec()`, and run it at the beginning of every static method.